# bundler won't run (no-deployment doesn't work)

Tags: ruby, bundler

I was fiddling around with the `--deployment` option on my ruby app. After that I wanted to add another gem to my app. I added it to the gemspec, and ran bundle install but the new gem didn't get installed. I deleted the vendor cache, .bundle, Gemfile.lock and tried again, and got the error I expected:

> You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>   ...

I had seen this before, so I proceeded to use `--no-deployment` flag. For some reason though, the same error popped up again. An hour later I'm still stuck in the same place. No matter what I do, I can't get bundle install to work and install the new gem.

Is this some sort of strange error? Or bundler by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pff... Somehow a .bundle config folder sneaked into my home directory, which made all repos on my machine look like deployment repos to bundler. Deleting the .bundle folder resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes, bundler has the "feature" to "remember" certain command-line options, which is very handy for things like `--without=production`, but also leads to some problems...

Answer (score 0):

You can list the current configurations by running

```
bundle config list
```

After that, if `deployment` is set to true, for instance, just do

```
bundle config set deployment false
```